# How to cleanly handle multiple conditions that are very similar to one another

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, branch

I'm trying to figure out a way to best handle multiple path files that are very similar to one another. While my code works, I feel like it's cumbersome, harder to maintain and difficult to scale without alot of manual work (For example suppose I need to keep adding more and more paths that are just slightly different.

Ideally, I would like to apply the DRY principle as much as possible and not have if-else statements all over the place if there is a better solution.

I thought that using dictionaries or a class might be some improvement but it felt cumbersome to also store paths in a dictionary. I'm not as experienced with classes so I couldn't get it to work without a ton of workarounds (I don't think I was constructing the class properly)

## Code

```
def save_df(df, banner, year, month):
    base_path = r'common\path\{0}\for\all\banners\{1}'.format(banner.upper(), year)

    if banner in ('a', 'b'):
        if month < 10:
            # The zero is so I can have the file month in '01, 02, etc.' format
            default_path = os.path.join(base_path, '{0}-0{1}_TEST'.format(year, month))
        else:
            default_path = os.path.join(base_path, '{0}-{1}_TEST'.format(year, month))
    else:
        if month < 10:
            default_path = os.path.join(base_path, '{0}_{1}-0{2}_TEST'.format(banner.upper(), year, month))
        else:
            default_path = os.path.join(base_path, '{0}_{1}-{2}_TEST'.format(banner.upper(), year, month))

    saved_output = [df, default_path]
    return saved_output
```

No problems for the path, works as intended. I believe the code can be improved by refactoring, however, I'm not sure the best way to go about handling conditions that are very similar without repetition.

Comment: For this particular case, you can use some of `str.format`'s options to simplify the inner condition. Using `"{month:0>2}".format(month=n)` will put a zero in front of any one-digit numbers.

Comment: Together with @jirassimok comment, you could "assume" one case and assign `default_path` according to that, and then just check with `if` for the other case and override the value.

Comment: Yeah I thought about that, but conceptually it doesn't make sense since each for the 4 banners are about equally like to be input. Also if in the future more banners are added with a slightly different path than what exists, I'd have to add in an 'else' anyway. 

Jirassimok's answer was really useful though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, it can sometimes be hard to avoid code duplication in cases like this. You could use dictionaries and tricky classes to generate special types of conditions, but that isn't usually worth it for a case this simple. It can make your code less readable, and readability is important.

Instead, stick to simpler techniques. There are three optimizations I might recommend for your code.

First, you can replace the inner conditional with a more advanced format string. Using `'{month:0>2}'.format(month=n)` will pad any one-digit months with a zero. (The `0` says to pad with zeros, the `>` says to right-align, and the `2` says to pad to at least 2 digits.)

Second, you can do something similar with the outer condition: use a variable that is `banner.upper() + '_'` in one case, and the empty string in the other case.

Third, you could write a function for the body of the branches, but this isn't really necessary after my other two suggestions.

```
def format_path(fmt, year, month, banner=None):
    if banner is None:
        banner = ''
    else:
        banner = banner.upper() + '_'
    return os.path.join(base_path, '{}{}-{:0>2}'.format(banner, year, month))
```

Comment: As an addendum, the general strategy represented by my second suggestion is to break down the things that each condition changes, try to move them out of the condition, and then combine those separate results without a condition.

Comment: Thanks! Your suggestions work without a hitch! The first recommendation is definitely getting implemented. I can see the second one being more useful if I get more and more banners.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary with keys that match your conditions:

```
import os

def save_df(df, banner, year, month):
    base_path = r'common\path\{0}\for\all\banner\{1}'.format(banner.upper(), year)

    # Each key is a tuple, left key is True if month is less than 10, 
    # right key is True if banner is equal to 'a' or 'b'
    formats = { # Key: (month_less_10, a_b_banner)
      (True, True): '{0}-0{1}_TEST'.format(year, month),
      (False, True): '{0}-{1}_TEST'.format(year, month),
      (True, False): '{0}_{1}-0{2}_TEST'.format(banner.upper(), year, month),
      (False, False): '{0}_{1}-{2}_TEST'.format(banner.upper(), year, month)
    }
    default_path = os.path.join(base_path, formats[(month < 10, banner in ('a', 'b'))]

    saved_output = [df, default_path]
    return saved_output
```